# How to read/get tags startTime/endTime, startDate and boolean value of isAllDayEvent for CalendarEvent?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm searching an event in "CalendarID" by "EventID" like this:

```js
var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalendarID).getEventSeriesById(EventID);
```

This "event" is a single `CalendarEvent`. Question: How can I get the next information of this CalendarEvent - `isAllDayEvent()`, `startTime`, `endTime` and `startDate`? Is it possible to find the way how can I get these tags?

Answer (score 0):

If you have calendarEvent, do this

```
Logger.log("Is all day? " + event.isAllDayEvent());
Logger.log("Start at: " + event.getStartTime());
Logger.log("End at: " + event.getEndTime());

if(event.isAllDayEvent()) {
  Logger.log("Start Date: " + event.getAllDayStartDate())
}
```

calendarEventSeries, however, is not very straightforward for getting a single event details the way you want. So you probably could add tags with relevant info and call `calendarEventSeries.getTag(key)` to retrieve the info. To get all the tag keys that are asoociated with the calendarEventSeries, use `calendarEventSeries.getAllTagKeys()` which returns a string array of keys. Currently, there is no way to getRecurrence of a calendarEventSeries. Here is a request to Google for adding this function. You could reply and up vote the request if you consider it is important feature to consider. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4064

Comment: thank you so much for fast answer, but I did it and I received the bad answer "TypeError: Cannot find function isAllDayEvent in object CalendarEventSeries. (row 204, file „Code“)"

Comment: You are trying to use the method for CalendarEvent on CalendarEventSeries. That won't work. You mentioned that the event is a single CalendarEvent. Try to call these methods on that single CalendarEvent object.

Comment: I created this event by method CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalendarID).createEvent("text",startTime,endTime); but because I need to search the same event I can use only method  "getEventSeriesById" (with using EvenID). Is it possible to use another right method? searching by EvenID?

Comment: Can you tell me if class CalendarEventSeries has the function of getRecurrence(recurrence, startTime, endTime) or anything other function with the same meaning? Or can I use the getTag(key) function? Thank you