# Ignore not All-Day events in the Google App Script Vacation Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've been customizing the [Vacation calendar script from google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar). Currently, I'm trying to prevent events that are not All-Day events from populating the shared calendar, but running into an issue. It doesn't seem like `event.isAllDayEvent()` is a [valid function anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260458/how-to-read-get-tags-starttime-endtime-startdate-and-boolean-value-of-isalldaye) or perhaps a Calendar.Event is different than a [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event)? How can I pull this information from the event?

```
/**
 * Determines if the given event should be imported into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user that is attending the event.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword being searched for.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event being considered.
 * @return {boolean} True if the event should be imported.
 */
function shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, event) {
  // Filters out events where the keyword did not appear in the summary
  // (that is, the keyword appeared in a different field, and are thus
  // is not likely to be relevant).
  if (event.summary.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  **if (!event.isAllDayEvent())
    // If the event is not an all day event, don't import it
    return false;**
  if (!event.organizer || event.organizer.email == user.getEmail()) {
    // If the user is the creator of the event, always imports it.
    return true;
  }
  // Only imports events the user has accepted.
  if (!event.attendees) return false;
  let matching = event.attendees.filter(function(attendee) {
    return attendee.self;
  });
  return matching.length > 0 && matching[0].responseStatus == 'accepted';
}
```

The above results in an error

> TypeError: event.isAllDayEvent is not a function

This import method gets the Event parameter via

```
/**
 * In a given user's calendar, looks for occurrences of the given keyword
 * in events within the specified date range and returns any such events
 * found.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user to retrieve events for.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword to look for.
 * @param {Date} start The starting date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} end The ending date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} optSince A date indicating the last time this script was run.
 * @return {Calendar.Event[]} An array of calendar events.
 */
function findEvents(user, keyword, start, end, optSince) {
  let params = {
    q: keyword,
    timeMin: formatDateAsRFC3339(start),
    timeMax: formatDateAsRFC3339(end),
    showDeleted: true,
  };
  if (optSince) {
    // This prevents the script from examining events that have not been
    // modified since the specified date (that is, the last time the
    // script was run).
    params.updatedMin = formatDateAsRFC3339(optSince);
  }
  let pageToken = null;
  let events = [];
  do {
    params.pageToken = pageToken;
    let response;
    try {
      response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error retriving events for %s, %s: %s; skipping',
          user, keyword, e.toString());
      continue;
    }
    events = events.concat(response.items.filter(function(item) {
      return shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, item);
    }));
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return events;
}
```

Comment: Hey Will, it seems like the second code snippet is missing a chunk as the ```while```statement is not there and also missing a curly brace.

Comment: Ah, it was there; I just hadn't included it in the code snippet. I'll include the full method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this issue and believe there is a difference between a `Calendar.Event` and a `CalendarEvent`. I modified the `shouldImportEvent` function to get a `CalendarEvent` by getting the user's calendar, then the event from the calendar, which worked.

```js
function shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, event) {
  // Filters out events where the keyword did not appear in the summary
  // (that is, the keyword appeared in a different field, and are thus
  // is not likely to be relevant).
  if (event.summary.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!event.organizer || event.organizer.email == user.getEmail()) {
    // If the user is the creator of the event, always imports it.
    return true;
  }
  // Only import events that are all day
  let calEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(user.getEmail()).getEventById(event.id)
  if (!calEvent.isAllDayEvent()) {
    return false;
  }
  // Only imports events the user has accepted.
  if (!event.attendees) return false;
  let matching = event.attendees.filter(function(attendee) {
    return attendee.self;
  });
  
  return matching.length > 0 && matching[0].responseStatus == 'accepted';
}
```